# How to display header and footer on each page using wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

Body content overlapping with header content.

How to make body content should render in proper format without overlapping the content.

Example like word document.

Header
Body
Footer

This is my controller code.

```
render :pdf => "#{@employee_full_name}-#{@template_name} Letter",
       :template => "/company/employee/download_employee.pdf.erb",
       :margin => {
             :top => 30,
             :bottom => 30
       },
       :header => {
           :html => {
               :template => '/company/employee/common_header.pdf.erb',
               :locals => {
                   header: @template_header
               }
           }
       },
       :footer => {
           :html => {
               :template => '/company/employee/common_footer.pdf.erb',
               :locals => {
                   footer: @template_footer
               }
           }
       },
       :disposition => "attachment"
```

Comment: Found any luck in solving this overlapping issue? It's still happening.